# Deploy NodeJS app with pm2 and Capistrano

Tags: node.js, capistrano, pm2

I develop project based on NodeJs, pm2, Capistrano 3.

Faced with problem of downtime while deploying Node app with Capistrano.

deploy.rb:

```
set :linked_dirs, ['node_modules', 'logs']
set :linked_files, ['ecosystem.json']

set :npm_flags, '--silent --no-spin'

before 'deploy:updated', 'assets:upload'
after 'deploy:updated', 'assets:webpack'
after 'deploy:publishing', 'pm2:restart'
```

assets:upload - builds js and css files and uploads to CDN. Build performs with Webpack so it's create webpack-assets.json.

assets:webpack - uploads webpack-assets.json to prod servers. webpack-assets.json is using by node to get exact asset name because it contains hash:

```
task :webpack do
    run_locally do
        roles(:web).each do |host|
            execute :rsync, '-rvzu', "themes-assets.json", "#{host.user}@#{host.hostname}:#{fetch(:release_path)}"
            execute :rsync, '-rvzu', "webpack-assets.json", "#{host.user}@#{host.hostname}:#{fetch(:release_path)}"
        end
    end
end
```

pm2:restart - should perform zero time reload. But in fact I'm getting 1second down time. If I perform this task independently there is no downtime.

```
def restart_app
        within current_path do
            execute :pm2, :startOrRestart, fetch(:deploy_to) + '/shared/ecosystem.json'
        end
    end
```

pm2 logs show the following error

```
Process with pid 123169 still not killed, retrying...
```

Comment: This tutorial may help you: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/tutorials/capistrano-like-deployments

Comment: maybe it is offtopic but there is a tool called shipit - https://github.com/shipitjs/shipit which is a capistrano clone on Node.js - maybe its worth checking (there is a short videocast about it: https://youtu.be/8PpBySjkWEM)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
pm2 startOrRestart <app|conf>
```

You have to use

```
pm2 startOrReload <app|conf>
```

If you still see a downtime while using "startOrReload", have a look at: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/signals-clean-restart/#graceful-start

Comment: I implemented [this](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-node-js-applications-with-capistrano) solution, but it still downtime

Comment: Can you replace the occurence "startOrRestart" in your capistrano file by "startOrReload"?

Comment: The problem occur only if use `cap production deploy`. If try `cap production pm2:restart` everything is OK.